Why QuestDB JOIN query is so slow?
I have a query and it executes very slowly in QuestDB, cannot wait the end of it, even if I increase my timeout to an hour
select t1.*, t2.*
from "a" t1
join "b" t2 on t1.sym=concat(t2.c1,'_',t2.c2) and t1.pid = cast(t2.pid as varchar)
where t1.ts between '2023-11-11T22:00' and '2023-11-12T22:00'
  and t2.ts between '2023-11-11T22:00' and '2023-11-12T22:00'


B is rather large table, around a billion records and A has a in hundred of thousands rows with this timestamp range. The result set is rather big but not astronomic. What can I do to optimize and make it run in reasonable time?
